# Event Aggregator in Prism usage giving exception

Tags: wpf, prism

I have to communicate between 2 view models so I am using Event aggregator but I observed the method is calling 2 times when a property is updated and for the first it is working as expected but second time all the elements are null and throwing null reference exception.

Why it is happening I am not triggering it second time.

MainViewModel

```
 private XMLNode NodeSelected;

    public XMLNode NodeSelected
    {
        get { return NodeSelected; }
        set
        {
            nodeSelected = value;
            iEventAggregator.GetEvent<AddNewObjectEvent>().Publish(this.NodeSelected);

        }
    }
```

UsercontrolViewModel

```
 public UserControlViewModel(IEventAggregator iEventAggregator)
    {
        this.iEventAggregator = iEventAggregator;
        this.iEventAggregator.GetEvent<AddNewGuiSyncObjectEvent>()
    .Subscribe(AddXMLNode);
    }
```

AddXMLNODE method related code

```
 private void AddXMLNODE (XMLNode SelectedNode)
    {
        if (this.CriteriaItem == null) return;
        SyncObject currentObj = new SyncObject(SelectedNode);
        if (!IsSyncItemNameUnique(currentObj))
        {
            currentObj.Name = GetUniqueName(currentObj);
        }
        this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.Add(currentObj);
        this.SelectedSyncObject = this.CriteriaItem .SyncObjects.LastOrDefault();
    }
```

Here first time "CriteriaItem" is coming correct and newnode is added to collection but again same method is hitting and CriteriaItem  is NULL If I remove that null check we are getting exception.

What is the mistake here I am not getting.

The complete code

UserControl ViewModel

```
namespace Hexagon.SmartUITest.GUISynchronization.ViewModel
{
    public class IndividualSyncViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region properties
        private GUISyncObject selectedSyncObject;
        public GUISyncObject SelectedSyncObject
        {
            get { return selectedSyncObject; }
            set
            {
                selectedSyncObject = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedSyncObject);
                iEventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectedSyncObjectEvent>().Publish(this.SelectedSyncObject);
            }
        }
        private SyncCriteriaItem _CriteriaItem;

        public SyncCriteriaItem CriteriaItem
        {
            get { return CriteriaItem; }
            set
            {
               CriteriaItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => this.CriteriaItem);
            }
        }

        private IEventAggregator iEventAggregator;
        #endregion

        #region constructor
        public IndividualSyncViewModel(IEventAggregator iEventAggregator)
        {
            this.iEventAggregator = iEventAggregator;
            this.iEventAggregator.GetEvent<AddNewGuiSyncObjectEvent>()
             .Subscribe(AddGUISyncItem);
        }

        #endregion



        private ICommand deleteSyncObjectClick;

        public ICommand DeleteSyncObjectClick
        {
            get
            {
                if (deleteSyncObjectClick == null) deleteSyncObjectClick = new RelayCommand(DeleteSync);
                return deleteSyncObjectClick;
            }
            set
            {
                deleteSyncObjectClick = value;
            }
        }
        private void DeleteSync()
        {
            this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.Remove(selectedSyncObject);
            selectedSyncObject = this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.LastOrDefault();
        }


        private bool IsItemNameUnique(GUISyncObject SyncObject)
        {
            if (this.CriteriaItem != null && this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.Count == 0)
                return true;

            foreach (GUISyncObject item in this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.ToList())
            {
                if (item.Name.Equals(SyncObject.Name) && !item.CommandNodeName.Equals(SyncObject.CommandNodeName))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private string GetUniqueName(GUISyncObject syncItem)
        {
            List<string> itemsNames = this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.Select(item => item.Name).ToList();
            return CommonNamingRules.GetUniqueName(itemsNames, syncItem.Name);
        }

        private void AddGUISyncItem(ControlNode SelectedNode)
        {
            if (this.CriteriaItem == null) return;
            GUISyncObject currentObj = new GUISyncObject(SelectedNode);
            if (!IsSyncItemNameUnique(currentObj))
            {
                currentObj.Name = GetUniqueName(currentObj);
            }
            this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.Add(currentObj);
            this.SelectedSyncObject = this.CriteriaItem.SyncObjects.LastOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

UserControl xaml.cs

```
public partial class IndividualSync : UserControl
{
    private IndividualSyncViewModel _vm;
    public IndividualSync()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         _vm = new IndividualSyncViewModel(Event.EventInstance.EventAggregator);
        rootGrid.DataContext = _vm;           
    }
    #region properties

    public SyncCriteriaItem SyncCriteriaItem
    {
        get { return (SyncCriteriaItem)GetValue(SyncCriteriaItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SyncCriteriaItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SyncCriteriaItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SyncCriteriaItem", typeof(SyncCriteriaItem), typeof(IndividualSync), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCriteriaItemSet));

    public GUISyncObject SelectedSYNC
    {
        get { return (GUISyncObject)GetValue(SelectedSYNCDependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedSYNCDependencyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedSYNCDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedSYNC", typeof(GUISyncObject), typeof(IndividualSync), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnGUISyncItemSelect));

    private static void OnCriteriaItemSet(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IndividualSync)d)._vm.CriteriaItem = e.NewValue as SyncCriteriaItem;
    }

    private static void OnSyncItemSelect(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       ((IndividualSync)d)._vm.SelectedSyncObject = e.NewValue as GUISyncObject;
    }
    #endregion


}
```

Iam creating two dependency properties on the usercontrol which will be set from parent usercontrol.

Parent usercontrol Xaml

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Converters:IndexToTabNameConverter x:Key="TabIndexConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SyncTabItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TabIndexConverter},
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}}}"/>
            <Button Margin="10,0,0,0"              
          Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}"
          ToolTipService.ToolTip="Save and Close">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Path Data="M0,0 L6,6 M6, 0 L0,6"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="1" />
                </Button.Content>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <uxt:EventToCommand  CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveSyncCriteriaCommand,ElementName=rootGrid}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>       
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EmptyTemplate">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Comic Sans" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <Label FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SyncCriteriaTemplate">
        <local:IndividualSync SyncCriteriaItem="{Binding}" SelectedGUISYNC="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedGUISYNCOBJECT}"/>
    </DataTemplate>        
    <DataTemplate x:Key="newTabButtonHeaderTemplate">         
        <telerik:RadButton Style="{DynamicResource IconButtonStyle}" Width="20" Height="20" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NewCommand,ElementName=rootGrid}" ToolTip="Click to add new item">
            <uxt:UxtXamlImage Template="{DynamicResource Com_Add}" />
        </telerik:RadButton>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemContentTemplate">
        <Grid/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Selectors:TabItemTemplateSelector x:Key="headerTemplateSelector"
                       NewButtonTemplate="{StaticResource newTabButtonHeaderTemplate}"
                       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SyncTabItemTemplate}"/>
    <Selectors:TabItemTemplateSelector x:Key="contentTemplateSelector"
                        NewButtonTemplate="{StaticResource itemContentTemplate}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SyncCriteriaTemplate}"/>
    <Selectors:SyncTemplateSelector x:Key="syncTemplates">          
        <Selectors:SyncTemplateSelector.ProcessSyncTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:Label Content="{Binding ProcessSync,StringFormat={}{0}}"  BorderThickness="1"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  FontStyle="Oblique" Width="{Binding Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadListBox}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Selectors:SyncTemplateSelector.ProcessSyncTemplate>
        <Selectors:SyncTemplateSelector.GUISyncTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="GUISYNC" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" Width="{Binding Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadListBox}}"  IsExpanded="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
                    <telerik:RadTabControl  ItemsSource="{Binding SyncCriteriaItem}" OverflowMode="Scroll"  DropDownDisplayMode="Visible"   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSyncCriteria, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0"
                                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource headerTemplateSelector}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource contentTemplateSelector}">                           
                    </telerik:RadTabControl>
                </Expander>                   
            </DataTemplate>
        </Selectors:SyncTemplateSelector.GUISyncTemplate>           
    </Selectors:SyncTemplateSelector>      
</UserControl.Resources>    

      <Grid Name="rootGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadListBox Margin="20,5,20,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="synclist"  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSyncObjectCollection.SyncObjects}"  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource syncTemplates}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSyncObject,Mode=TwoWay}" >            
    </telerik:RadListBox>
    <telerik:RadComboBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="SyncOption" EmptyText="Select a sync type to be added " Margin="0,8,0,5"  EmptySelectionBoxTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SyncTypes}"  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=synclist}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="25" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSyncIndex,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <uxt:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AddSelectedSyncClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedValue,ElementName=SyncOption}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
    <telerik:RadButton Style="{DynamicResource IconButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SelectedSyncObject,Converter={uxt:ObjectToBoolConverter}}"  ToolTip="Click to delete selected Sync"                            
                           Command="{Binding DeleteSyncObjectClick}">
        <uxt:UxtXamlImage Template="{DynamicResource Com_Delete}" />
    </telerik:RadButton>
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help. I have debugged the code and I observed even two Items are binded for CriteriaItems Breakpoint hitting for dependency property criteria item 3 times and one time null is coming.

Even when  I change Tab selection Dependency Property setting code is hitting 2 times instead of one time.first time null is setting for CriteriaItem and second time respective item is coming.

Comment: It all about debugging. You can put break point one in                                  public UserControlViewModel(IEventAggregator iEventAggregator)  and other in AddXML Node and at Publish events. The first method hit will tell how many times the event has subscribed. When hitting the method or Publish statement open call stack and see from where the call is routing. Call stack is available in Debug >Windows >Call Stack only while debugging

Comment: `NodeSelected.get` will raise an stack overflow error. Who sets `CriteriaItem`? `NodeSelected.set` raises publishes `AddNewObjectEvent` while `UserControlViewModel` subscribes to `AddNewGuiSyncObjectEvent` - what do they have to do with each other?

Comment: @Haukinger CriteriaItem is a dependency property on usercontrol when usercontrol hosted.I didn't provided complete code here.
Once SelectedNode raises the event it will be added to collection of syncobjects on  criteriaitem and dispalyed in RadGridView.

Comment: No, it will not, because you raise one event but subscribe to another. That being said, all the code you provided isn't helpful at all because it doesn't write `CriteriaItem`, so how should anyone know who or why it is set to `null`?

Comment: Ok I will give complete code

Comment: I suggest, you fix the `StackOverflowException`s in your code first. And there's still no communication happening between `MainViewModel` and `UsercontrolViewModel`.